# Android kotlin unit test - Exception in thread "Test worker @coroutine#4" io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: View(#1)

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, coroutine, mockk

I'm writing the unit test of a presenter that fetches data from an API :

```
class SearchPresenter constructor(
    private val view: SearchContract.View,
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val dispatcherProvider: DispatcherProvider,
    private val userService: UserService
) : SearchContract.Presenter {

    override fun fetchData() {
        coroutineScope.launch(dispatcherProvider.io) {
            val response = withContext(dispatcherProvider.io) {
                userService.getUsers(1u)
            }
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                view.displayUsers(response.body()!!.data)
            } else {
                view.displayError()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use 2 different dispatcher depending on the context (test or not):

```
interface DispatcherProvider {
    val main: CoroutineDispatcher
    val io: CoroutineDispatcher
    val default: CoroutineDispatcher
}

class DefaultDispatcher : DispatcherProvider {
    override val main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Main
    override val io: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.IO
    override val default: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = Dispatchers.Default
}
```

For my test I use this Dispatcher:

```
class DispatcherProviderTest : DispatcherProvider {
    override val main: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    override val io: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    override val default: CoroutineDispatcher
        get() = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
}
```

Here is my presenter test class:

```
class SearchPresenterTest : CoroutineBasedTest() {
    lateinit var view: SearchContract.View
    lateinit var presenter: SearchPresenter
    lateinit var dispatcherProvider: DispatcherProvider
    lateinit var userService: UserService


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        view = mockk()
        userService = mockk(relaxed = true)
        dispatcherProvider = testCoroutineContextProvider
        presenter = SearchPresenter(view, coroutineScope.scope, dispatcherProvider, userService)
    }


    @Test
    fun testSuccess() {
        val users = listOf<UserPreview>(
            UserPreview(
                "testId",
                "testTitle",
                "testFirstName",
                "testLastName",
                "test.jpg"
            )
        )
        coEvery {
            userService.getUsers(1u)
        } answers {
            Response.success(
                Page(
                    users, 1u
                )
            )
        }
        presenter.fetchData()
        verify { view.displayUsers(users) }
    }
```

This class inherits from CoroutineBasedTest:

```
abstract class CoroutineBasedTest {

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineScope = TestCoroutineScopeRule()

    protected val testCoroutineContextProvider = DispatcherProviderTest()


    class TestCoroutineScopeRule : TestWatcher() {

        lateinit var scope: CoroutineScope
        val mainThreadSurrogate = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

        override fun starting(description: Description?) {
            super.starting(description)
            scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + mainThreadSurrogate)
        }

        override fun finished(description: Description?) {
            super.finished(description)
            scope.cancel()
        }
    }

}
```

I must have a problem with the scope or dispatcher not being properly cleaned. But I can't find the fix it.
When I run the test, I have a successful result but with this exception:

> Exception in thread "Test worker @coroutine#4"
> io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for:
> View(#1).displayUsers([UserPreview(id=testId, title=testTitle,
> firstName=testFirstName, lastName=testLastName, picture=test.jpg)])
> at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.defaultAnswer(MockKStub.kt:93)  at
> io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)  at
> io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
> at
> io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
> at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:266)
> at
> io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:23)
> at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:21)    at
> io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.BaseAdvice.handle(BaseAdvice.kt:42)     at
> io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.jvm.JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.interceptNoSuper(JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.java:45)
> at
> com.thefork.challenge.search.SearchContract$View$Subclass0.displayUsers(Unknown
> Source)   at
> com.thefork.challenge.search.SearchPresenter$fetchData$1.invokeSuspend(SearchPresenter.kt:24)
> at
> kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)     at
> kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:45)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:322)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)     at
> kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)     at
> com.thefork.challenge.search.SearchPresenter.fetchData(SearchPresenter.kt:19)
> at
> com.thefork.challenge.search.SearchPresenterTest.testSuccess(SearchPresenterTest.kt:53)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
> at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)  at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)    at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)     at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:121)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)  Suppressed:
> kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException:
> [CoroutineId(4),
> "coroutine#4":StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@34af8dd6,
> TestCoroutineDispatcher[scheduler=kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScheduler@6637b783]]
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s

Comment: You just need to write something like every { view.displayUsers(users) } just runs or add relaxed=true. Your call is not mocked, but the test completes successfully - the method is called.

Comment: My test complete successfully already. However, I still have this exception which is triggered during the test.  I tried making the changes you mentioned but to no result. (I may have misunderstood)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an "answer" for the call in question?

```
coEvery { 
    view.displayUsers(users)
} answers { 
    // some response
}
```

That might get that error log to go away.

As for the test passing even though there is an error, this can happen often when the exception itself happens in a background coroutine that does not run on the current thread. This is because in a test, the "default uncaught thread exception handler" for background threads just logs an error. You could try wrapping the test in something like

```
dispatcherProvider.io.runBlockingTest {
   ...
}
```

to see if that helps surface the error.